# Random method result to a zero and a negative error android programming:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: -5

Tags: android

Am trying to randomize my items between a max value and a minimum value but am getting an error exception of n<=0 :-5.  this my code in android please help.

```
 level1 = new Random();
        x1= level1.nextInt((9 - 1) + 1)+1;
        levelone.setText(Integer.toString(x1));

        level3 = new Random();
        x3= level3.nextInt((9 - 1) + 1)+1;
        levelthree.setText(Integer.toString(x3));

        level3 = new Random();
        v0= level3.nextInt((9 - 1) + 1)+1;

        v1=x3*v0;
        v2 = (v1/x1);

        level2 = new Random();
        x2= level2.nextInt((9 - (v2-1)) + 1)+(v2-1);
        leveltwo.setText(Integer.toString(x2));
```

.this the line with the error.

```
x2= level2.nextInt((9 - (v2-1)) + 1)+(v2-1);
```

All my max and min are inclusive.

**Error Log:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{munene.com.mathgame/munene.com.mathgame.MathLevel2Activity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: -5
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: -5
                                                     at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:175)
                                                     at munene.com.mathgame.MathLevel2Activity.generateFormular07(MathLevel2Activity.java:501)
                                                     at munene.com.mathgame.MathLevel2Activity.onCreate(MathLevel2Activity.java:52)
```

Comment: v2 >9.  So nextInt throws an exception because it needs to be passed a positive number.  How to fix it-  no clue, your code is completely non-descriptive of what you're trying to actually do.  Name your variables with what they actually store, nobody can guess what v2 is.

Comment: v2 is a variable where am trying to get a random value b2n the two ranges so as i can be able to create the final expression..My question is how can make the result positive..or handle the negative or check the negative.

Comment: If you want a random value between X and Y with Y>X, its random.nextInt(y-x+1)+x;   And that's it, it only needs to be called once.  What you're doing calling nextInt 3 times to get 1 random number I have no idea.

Comment: guess its because x1,x2,x3,x4 are supposed to be different values.

Answer (score 0):

Here are your various assignments:

> ```
> x1= level1.nextInt((9 - 1) + 1)+1;
> x3= level3.nextInt((9 - 1) + 1)+1;
> v0= level3.nextInt((9 - 1) + 1)+1;
> ```

Each of these variables (`x1`, `x3`, and `v0`) now holds a value between 1 and 9.

> ```
> v1=x3*v0;
> ```

`v1` now holds a value between 1 and 81 (lower bound is 1*1 = 1 and upper bound is 9*9 = 81).

> ```
> v2 = (v1/x1);
> ```

`v2` now holds a value between 0 and 81 (lower bound is 1/9 = 0 and upper bound is 81/1 = 81).

So now you call this:

> ```
> x2= level2.nextInt((9 - (v2-1)) + 1)+(v2-1);
> ```

The important part being `nextInt((9 - (v2-1)) + 1)`. Since `v2` could be anything from 0 through 81, this could be anything from `nextInt(-70)` to `nextInt(11)`.

From the documentation for `Random.nextInt(int bound)`:

> **Parameters**
>
> bound `int`: the upper bound (exclusive). Must be positive.

So you will have to change your last call (your assignment to `x2`) to guarantee that you will never pass a negative number.

Comment: So how can i change x2? please? suggestion

Comment: That depends entirely on what you're trying to do, which as Gabe said is totally unclear.

Comment: Its a game. This are just formulas i want to use in the game..the line with the error ,am intending to randomize the value so as it finally meet this expression. 
        x0 = ((x1*x2) -x4)/x3;

Comment: Well only you can decide which formulas and random numbers work for your game. But right now as a quick fix you could change `.nextInt((9 - (v2-1)) + 1)` to `.nextInt((9 - (v2-1)) + 71)`.

Comment: thanks. just asking .how did you get the 71? because have alot of similar cases.

Comment: See the answer for details. Your `.nextInt((9 - (v2-1)) + 1)` call has a range of possible values, from `-70` to `11`. Since the minimum allowed value to `nextInt()` is 0, you have to add 70 to whatever you're already doing.

Comment: What if am not using 9..but 4,6,5 and three..what should i add?

Comment: You should stop looking for the quick fix and actually think about what you're trying to do and what range of values that could cause you app. What you have right now is a mess, adding random numbers you don't understand to an algorithm he doesn't understand is just asking for bugs